# Обработка MAILER-DAEMON@site.ru писем через IMAP

Tags: php, email, imap, откат

Обрабатываю bounce-письма (откаты/возвраты после отправки на несуществующий email-адрес), пытаясь сохранить их в свою таблицу MySQL. Из писем берется: тема письма, текст сообщения, адрес на которой не было отправлено письмо и пришел откат. 
И вот последнее как раз таки не знаю как определить, ведь все письма-откаты у меня в ящике имеют адрес: MAILER-DAEMON@site.ru, где site.ru - домен моего сайта (site.ru конечно же взят для примера, домен у меня другой).

Получается это почтовый демон на моём почтовом сервере мне откаты присылает?

Как же в письме найти адрес-получателя тогда - т.е. email-адрес письма которое ранее не отправилось и мне в обратку пришел откат.

Comment: Полный текст письма посмотрите, почтовый сервер обычно заголовки не доставленного письма посылает в тексте своего письма

Answer (score 1):

В правильно форматированных "письмах-откатах" (Delivery Status Notifications) есть отдельный MIME-контейнер типа `Content-Type: message/delivery-status`, который следует формату, описанному в [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464). Вас интересуют Original-Recipient и Final-Recipient.